# Parsing JSON array based on value/key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm looking to parse this JSON array and display the available locations in a structured list and am having a hard time wrapping my head around where to begin.

So the data is parsed to HTML based on the date selected, but in a side bar it needs to show the available locations based on the keys in the 'location' value - but this parsing needs to be structured in a tree like the HTML below. Is there an efficient way to accomplish this? The HTML and JSON can be tweaked slightly or have data attributes added if that helps accomplish this in a more elegant way. Thanks!

This is the sample JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "New York",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Los Angeles",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "San Francisco",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Chicago",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Europe",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Asia",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  }
]
```

This is the the structure in which it should be output

```
<ul>
<li data-location="USA" class="collapsable">USA
    <ul class="cities">
        <li data-location="los-angeles">Los Angeles</li>
        <li data-location="new-york">New York</li>
        <li data-location="san-francisco">San Francisco</li>
        <li data-location="chicago">Chicago</li>
        <li data-location="philadelphia">Philadelphia</li>
        <li data-location="detroit">Detroit</li>
        <li data-location="atlanta">Atlanta</li>
        <li data-location="new-orleans">New Orleans</li>
        <li data-location="washington-dc">Washington D.C.</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li data-location="europe">Europe</li>
<li data-location="asia">Asia</li>
<li data-location="south-america">South America</li>
<li data-location="africa">Africa</li>
<li data-location="australia">Australia</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @depperm i tried a long series of if statements but i felt like there must be a better way...

Comment: You can do this with a loop, but then you would have to determine in your data what is a a city and what is a continent.

Comment: This looks like homework, and I hesitate to help if you haven't attempted any code, but I think part of what's causing you to be stumped, is that you referred to "location" as the value. "location" is a key, and when you go through each object in the sample array, you can get the value of "location" simply by calling objectInstance["location"]. That will get you started. It's up to you to figure out what data needs to be added to the sample JSON to determine if a location is a city or a continent, and whether you need to keep track of a "parent" location, or if all cities are just under USA.

Comment: thanks @MHardwick was mainly just having a brain gap where a small problem was looking like a bigger one, but thanks for the idea and you're right that just adding in the parent category/continent into the data array clears up the whole problem that was for some reason stumping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to create a dynamic html using the json object. You may try the following. ( Remember the following code only provides the logic you need to implement, based on your requirement you may need to change the Json structure or jquery )

```
  <ul class="cities">      
    </ul>

<script>
var data = [
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "New York",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Los Angeles",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "San Francisco",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Chicago",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Europe",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://link.com",
    "title": "Illustration ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "location": "Asia",
    "date": "June 19, 2015"
  }
];



 $().ready(function(){
var parsed = JSON.stringify(data); // get the json string 
var obj = $.parseJSON(parsed); // convert json string into json object

$.each(obj,function(i)
{
   $(".cities").append("<li data-location='" + obj[i]["location"] + "'>" + obj[i]["location"] + "</li>");
});
});
<script>
```

UPDATE : To avoid duplicates

```
var objArr = new Array;     
$.each(obj,function(i)
{
    if(objArr.indexOf(obj[i]["location"]) == -1)
    {
      objArr.push(obj[i]["location"]);     
     $(".cities").append("<li data-location='" + obj[i]["location"] + "'>" +    obj[i]["location"] + "</li>");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! this will get me most of the way on logic, thanks for the outline.

Comment: actually is there a way to avoid duplicating the prints if there are multiple objects from say Los Angeles?

Comment: please refer to the UPDATE section